# add elipsis on the last line of text

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add elipsis on last line my markeup is:

```
<h4 class="heading4 js-heading4">Yellow gold Yellow gold Yellow gold</h4>


.heading4 {
    height: 98px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

I want my output should be like **Yellow gold Yellow gold Yellow go...**

if text is overflow.
problem is if i am adding `text-overflow:ellipsis` then whole text is coming in one line like :
 **Yellow gold Yellow gold Yell...** i want to add ellipsis at the bottom of page.

Comment: sorry, it's unclear to me...

Comment: You may want to look into dotdotdot.jquery.

Comment: many spell errors like `elipsis` and `oveflow` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

With standard CSS, no. You can't.

But, there are non-standard browser specific CSS which do this. e.g. `webkit` based browsers support this (esp. Chrome) using `-webkit-line-clamp`:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/C34Gm/1/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
p {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

***Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions***

***Note***: These "Webkit Extensions" are proprietary webkit-prefixed properties. Do not use on production web sites, at least as of now.

Comment: i need this for mobile browser so will it work for mobile ?

Comment: @SachinRawal: Which mobile and which browser? As I said, this is a `webkit` only proprietary extension. It works on Safari on iOS. It will also work on Chrome. Apart from that, hard luck. Why don't you try using that fiddle on your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery plugin to automatically create eclipses on the end of the text as per your requirement without reinventing the wheel:

```
http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/
```